# Can the HTTP-Header be send long before the whole body using HTTPS

Tags: http, https, header, webserver

I've heared that you (in some cases) can prevent timeouts by sending the HTTP-header back to the client before the whole HTTP-body is prepared.

I know that this is impossible using gzip ... but is this possible using HTTPS?

I read in some posts that the *secure* part of HTTPS is done in the transport-layer (TLS/SSL) - therefore it should be possible, right?

Sorry for mixing gzip in here - it's a completely different level - I know ... and it may is more confusing than giving an example ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In HTTP 1.1 it's possible to send the response header before preparing of the body of the response is completed . To do this one normally uses chunked encoding.

Some servers also stream the data as is by not specifying the content length and indicating the end of stream by closing connection, but this is quite a brutal way to do things (chunked encoding was designed exactly for sending the data before it's completely available).

As HTTP(S) is HTTP running over SSL/TLS channel, TLS doesn't affect the above behavior in any way.

Comment: Is there an example for how to do this?

Comment: @liang StackOverflow is a Q&A site, not a forum with samples.

Comment: sample can be thought of as constructive answers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this. HTTPS is just HTTP over an TLS/SSL transport, the HTTP protocol is exactly the same.